# How to fail a manual release if it has not been deployed to upstream environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

How can we configure a manual release promotion to fail if the release has not been deployed to an upstream environment?  All the environments are under one release definition/pipeline.

Use Case: A manual deployment to Prod fails if the release has not been deployed to UAT.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of a built in way to do that, but you could create a deployment gate that calls a rest api or an azure function that queries the status of the previous environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a PowerShell task at the beginning the Prod ennvironmetn, things need to be achieved in PowerShell script as below:

#### 1. Get the status of the UAT for current release

Use the REST API [Get release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/get%20release?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get details for current release:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=4.1-preview.6
```

Then get the status of UAT environment from the response.

#### 2. Fail the PowerShell task if the status is not succeeded

If the UAT status not equal `succeeded` (such as the status is `rejected`), then fail the PowerShell task by `exit 1`. So the Prod environment will fail.